# How to extract properties from html Canvas CanvasGradient and CanvasPattern objects

Tags: javascript, canvas, reflection, html5-canvas

Given: an html canvas context:

Example code:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/wJ67M/

This code creates a `CanvasGradient` object in the gradient variable.

```
var gradient=context.createLinearGradient(0,0,300,150);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');   
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');
```

This code creates a `CanvasGradient` object in the gradient variable.

```
var gradient=context.createRadialGradient(150,150,30, 150,150,100);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');   
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'white');
```

This code creates a `CanvasPattern` object in the pattern variable.

```
var pattern=context.createPattern(myImage,'repeat');
```

**Is there a programatic way of extracting the properties from these objects after they are created (not by referring back to the JS code that created them)?**

Wanted:

- The linear gradients line segment (0,0,300,150) and its colorstops (0,red,1,white).
- The radial gradients circles (150,150,30, 150,150,100) and its colorstops (0,red,1,white).
- The patterns image and repeat properties.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canvas specs does not grant access to the inner gradient or pattern properties, just like, as you also know, one cannot get access to the transform matrix.
    So the only solution is to inject CanvasRenderingContext2D, CanvasGradient and CanvasPattern prototypes to store, in the created objects, the values used to create them.

So for the Canvas, you can write something like :

```
// save native linear gradient function
var nativeCreateLinearGradient = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.createLinearGradient ;

// redefine createLinearGradient with a function that stores creation data
// new properties : gradientType, x0, y0, x1, y1, colorStops
CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.createLinearGradient = function(x0, y0, x1, y1) {
      // actually create the gradient
      var newGradient = nativeCreateLinearGradient.apply(this,arguments);
      // store creation data
      newGradient.gradientType = 0 ; // 0 for linear, 1 for radial
      newGradient.x0 = x0;         newGradient.y0 = y0;
      newGradient.x1 = x1;         newGradient.y1 = y1;
      newGradient.colorStops = [];
      return newGradient;
};
```

And for the Gradient :

```
var dummyContext = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');    

var nativeAddColorStop = CanvasGradient.prototype.addColorStop;

CanvasGradient.prototype.addColorStop = function (offset, color) {
      // evaluate offset (to avoid reference issues)
      offset = +offset;
      // evaluate color (to avoid reference issues)
      dummyContext.fillStyle = color;
      color = dummyContext.fillStyle ;
      // store color stop 
      this.colorStops.push([offset, color]);
      // build the real gradient
      nativeAddColorStop.call(this, offset, color);  
      return this;     
};
```

You can do this in a very similar way for the radial gradient, and for the pattern you might want to copy the image, which type is [CanvasImageSource](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#canvasimagesource) )

Comment: +1 Thanks @GameAlchemist!  I'm using a similar workaround now, but I was hoping someone had "jailbreaked" the CanvasGradient and CanvasPattern objects.